# Draw a square given 2 corners

Tags: c++, geometry

I am at the moment trying to come up with a simple method to extract some data points, given two corners.

```
A***************
****************
***************B
```

I tried to illustrate my situation above.
Given corner A and B (x,y,z) how do generate the (x,y,z) coordinate for all the * in the square?

Comment: "sphere" and "square" are different things.

Comment: square - corrected.

Comment: Is that a discrete grid? Otherwise the set of those is infinitely big.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use integer for the coordinates. You could do something like the following:

```
for (int z = A.z; z <= B.z; z++) {
    for (int y = A.y; y <= B.y; y++) {
        for (int x = A.x; x <= B.x; x++) {
            // Do things here.. You can get the coordinates from the x, y, and z variables.
        }
    }
}
```

This will basically iterate through every point (*) including the point given (A and B).

---

I don't know what you're looking for but it seems to me this is what you ask.

Here's a fast example without using z (tested with [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/2oqd)):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

struct point {
    int x, y, z;
} A, B;

int main()
{
    A.x = 3;
    A.y = 4;
    //A.z = 0;

    B.x = 7;
    B.y = 5;
    //B.z = 0;
    //for (int z = A.z; z <= B.z; z++) {
        for (int y = A.y; y <= B.y; y++) {
            for (int x = A.x; x <= B.x; x++) {
                // Do things here.. You can get the coordinates from the x, y, and z variables.
                if (x == A.x && y == A.y) printf("A[%i, %i]", A.x, A.y);
                else if (x == B.x && y == B.y) printf("B[%i, %i]", B.x, B.y);
                else printf("[%i, %i]", x, y);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    //}
}
```

Example above will print all the coordinates like so: `[x, y]`. Oh, and also the above example won't work if B is smaller than A.. Need to do something about that, probably a check or even a dynamic approach.

Comment: Could the information the data be stored in a matrix like structure, instead of printing it..

Comment: @Lamda Wouldn't you just put it into a vector (for example: Vector4 or Vector3 or i could say a 4x1 or 3x1 matrix)? As you can easily multiply a matrix with a vector (4x4 * 4x1 or 3x3 * 3x1). Sorry if i'm getting the wrong idea here..